# Deploying asp.net mvc4 to IIS 7.5 locally

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I'm trying to deploy my ASP.NET website locally to IIS 7.5 on Windows 7, and I keep receiving the same error. I've never deployed to IIS before.

**Error:**

```
Authorization: Cannot verify acces to path (c:\inetpub\wwwroot\website)
```

**Message:**

> The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a
>   built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS
>   Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make
>   sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the
>   physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the
>   application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify
>   that \$ has Read access to the physical path.
>   Then test these settings again.

I'm using the .NET Framework 4.0.30319

Comment: Have you tried running VS with administrator permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was to do with the permissions set in the Application Pool, they must be correct in order for the application to run locally on IIS.

```
Application Pools
 -> Right click Pool
 -> Advanced Settings
 -> Process Model
    -> Identity
```

And my identity was set to the email used for the particular application